# Where does PyCharm save text files by default? And if it is to the directory file with the software in, where has my code gone wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

My code does not appear to be creating the file.  I don't know what I would be doing wrong as I have done my best to copy the template from the book I am learning from.  I generate no errors, but no text files are created.  This is a function that I am testing - charName is a variable with a user-defined value.

```
import pickle

charName = 'Joe'
charAttr = {'Power':'5','Health':'5','Wisdom':'5','Dexterity':'5'}

def fileCreateWrite():

    charAttrFile=open(charName + '.txt','x')
    fileInfo=dumps(charAttr)
    fileInfo=charName + '/n' + fileInfo
    charAttrFile.write(fileInfo)
    charAttrFile.close
fileCreateWrite()
```

Comment: I feel really stupid as did not actually call the function.  I was being thick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give it a relative path, as you have in the case of your example program, it will create the file in whatever the [current working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is. This will, in most cases, be *where you launched the application from*, not where the application actually is.

As an aside, it's better practice to use the `with` syntax with `open` so that you do not have to manually close the file, EX:

```
def fileCreateWrite():

   with open(charName + '.txt','x') as charAttrFile:
       fileInfo=dumps(charAttr)
       fileInfo=charName + '/n' + fileInfo
       charAttrFile.write(fileInfo)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I still can't get pickle.dumps(object) to work (I played around a bit and got bored), so have told the dictionary it's a string.

    myDictionaryString=str(myDictionary)

which I can then write to a text file.  I was being thick as did not call function (which was the original issue).  I won't be posting late night questions again.

Comment: You know I didn't even really look at your code, just answered the actual question you asked. With ``pickle``, you're saving an object to a file. So you'd do ``pickle.dumps(charAttr, charAttrFile)``. But you could not write anything else to that file without breaking it.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't really expect people had.  So the way I attempted to do it was wrong because I was mixing pickles and strings.  Makes sense.